# flattening line from noise

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, signal-processing

I have group of points that when plotted are creating the blue line. How can I calculate the red line?

**Note**: I plotted it with paint in windows, but generally speaking I what the blue line flattened to be close to the red line.

Thanks

[image: link to the image- blue line is the input, red should be the output]

Comment: Try performing interpolation. It would be helpful if your dataset was known. Is this a specific function?

Comment: You plotted this in paint? Do you mean you just sketched the red line by hand? If not, how was it generated?

Comment: Try a moving average on like $7$ points.

Comment: @kccu the red line with paint, the blue line with python matplotlib.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I already tried that but it give lagging results and somtime it won't catch some curves if they are so close (depends on the moving average number)

Comment: @an4s tried savgol_filter from scipy.signal library in python. but the results weren't smooth enough

Comment: Lagging is fixed by shifting the average by n/2. Do not trust too much human judgement on such signal processing: it is subjective.

Comment: @orr Try interpolation instead e.g., scipy.interpolate. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072844/add-more-sample-points-to-data) for an example.

Comment: @orr You are going to lose some of the higher frequency detail by smoothing; it is unavoidable.

Comment: @an4s looked into it and it seems like there are a lot of functions that all only **smoothing** and **not flattening**, could you specify what method you ment exactly?